# jQuery datatable re-grouping

Tags: jquery, row, datatables, grouping

I am using jQuery datatables row grouping.

```
 $('#report').dataTable({
    "bRetrieve": true
    }).rowGrouping({
    iGroupingColumnIndex: 3,
    bExpandableGrouping: true
 });
```

How do i re-group this table say on columnIndex:2 ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm dealing with it right now, would be nice if you found out a solution.